# rails generated CSV file can't be downloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export my database to CSV file and download it but it doesn't download. I have a form with 2 different actions, Export to CSV and Export to JSON I want to when I click any submit button of them to download the generated file but it doesn't work.
When Enter the city name and click the Export to CSV submit button it doesn't download

the view `export.html.erb`

```rb
<h1>Export Data</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <%= form_with(url: export_path, method: 'get', local: true) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :City, style: "font-weight: bolder; font-size: large;" %>
          <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :Date, style: "font-weight: bolder; font-size: large;" %>
          <%= f.datetime_local_field :date, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit "Export to CSV", class: "btn btn-primary" %> |
          <%= f.submit "Export to JSON", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question might give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814673/in-rails-how-can-i-submit-a-form-and-request-a-csv-formatted-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, guys I finally solved the issue. Actually, it was more than one reason that caused it.

First I replaced this line:

```rb
<%= form_with(url: export_path, method: 'get', local: true) do |f| %>
```

with this line:

```rb
<%= form_with(url: export_path(format: "csv") , method: 'get', local: true) do |f| %>
```

thanks to my friend [Jamie Crone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13788480/jamie-crone)

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
<%= form_with(url: export_path, method: 'get', local: true) do |f| %>
```

with...

```
<%= form_with(url: export_path, method: 'get', local: true, format: :csv) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score -1):

does anything download if you put this in the browser http://localhost:3000/export_path.pdf

Try changing this

```
<%= form_with(url: export_path, method: 'get', local: true) do |f| %>
```

with this

```
<%= form_with(url: export_path(format: "csv") , method: 'get', local: true) do |f| %>
```